# Can't round corners and have background colour on ASDisplayNode

Tags: ios, swift, textures, asyncdisplaykit

I am trying to create an ASDisplayNode with rounded corners whilst setting its background colour. However, the corners never appear rounded. Why is this? My code:

```
final class MyNode: ASDisplayNode {
    init() {
        self.backgroundColor = .red
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.cornerRadius = 10
        self.cornerRoundingType = .precomposited
    }

    ...
}
```

This just creates a rectangle that doesn't have rounded corners...

Comment: try delete this line self.cornerRoundingType = .precomposited

Comment: @aiwiguna that worked! Thanks. Why is that?

Comment: @aiwiguna ah but actually there's performance issues associated with that apparently...

Answer (score 0):

remove this line

```
self.cornerRoundingType = .precomposited
```

I am not really sure how the cornerRoundingType precomposited work too

In the code documentation said

```
* - ASCornerRoundingTypePrecomposited: corners are drawn using bezier paths to clip the content in a
 * CGContext / UIGraphicsContext. This requires .backgroundColor and .cornerRadius to be set. Use opaque
 * background colors when possible for optimal efficiency, but transparent colors are supported and much
 * more efficient than CALayer. The only limitation of this approach is that it cannot clip children, and
 * thus works best for ASImageNodes or containers showing a background around their children.
 *
```

there is someone asking about that in the repo [issue](https://github.com/TextureGroup/Texture/issues/1102) too